# SQL to produce desired output

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

From data which looks like the following (in a MySQL database):

```
mysql> select * from test;
+------------+--------+
| start      | name   |
+------------+--------+
| 2013-04-01 | Donald |
| 2013-04-02 | Daisy  |
| 2013-04-03 | Mickey |
| 2013-04-03 | Minnie |
| 2013-04-01 | Pluto  |
| 2013-04-02 | Goofy  |
+------------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to write a query to produce output which looks like:

```
2013-04-01  2013-04-02  2013-04003
----------  ----------  ----------
Donald      Daisy       Mickey
Pluto       Goofy       Minnie
```

Can someone suggest the SQL query to produce this output?

If it is helpful, this is the code I used to create the sample data.

```
create table test (
    start date,
    name varchar (20));

insert into test values ('2013-04-01','Donald');
insert into test values ('2013-04-02','Daisy');
insert into test values ('2013-04-03','Mickey');
insert into test values ('2013-04-03','Minnie');
insert into test values ('2013-04-01','Pluto');
insert into test values ('2013-04-02','Goofy');`
```

Comment: How Donald, Daisy and Mickey come in  first row? (what's relation)

Comment: I can not really answer as I am not MySQL person. But I guess you need Dynamic Pivot Feature (which is available in MS SQL as PIVOT and UNPIVOT operators). This might help: http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html

Comment: the relationship is the date.  donald, daisy and mickey are dated 1, 2 & 3 respectively.  pluto, goofy & minnie are each dated 1,2 & 3. Those dated 1 will appear in the first column i.e. donald and pluto.  the essence of the problem is to present names below a column headed by their associated date.

Comment: Thank you Learner, that link looks helpful.  It will take me some time to digest its contents.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user2593733 - I understand what you want but if you want to group data by date then why did you set Daisy in first row while date of Daisy and Goofy is same?

Comment: hims056, i did this to reflect the reality that rows can be entered into a database in any order.  The order of rows in a table should be irrevelant, if we want ordered output then we use the order by clause. I did not want to use data that worked only for a special case.  I hope I have made sense.

Comment: @user2593733 - Side note: use [`@Username`](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) in comments to reply specific person. So he get a notification. (I didn't get notification of your previous comment)

Comment: Why do you want the output like that (it seems odd), why not just group by `start`?

Answer (score 1):

Going to have to have a pivot table or a series of case statements.

```
Select 
      Case When Start = '2013-04-01' Then name End As '2013-04-01',
      Case When Start = '2013-04-02' Then name End As '2013-04-02',
      Case When Start = '2013-04-03' Then name End As '2013-04-03'
From Test;
```

Going to be a little more difficult to produce this dynamically if the table is more complex.  It is much easier to do this with larger data by simply exporting to excel and using the pivot table features.

Comment: I suppose he needs dynamic solution and not with hard-coded dates.

Comment: Ultimately I was hoping for a dynamic solution.  But this is the first step in achieving that goal.  Thank again for your input.

Answer (score 1):

From the given data structure you can't get your desired output. Because there is not any relation between records (e.g. Id etc.)

If we use `GROUP_CONCAT()` like this:

```
Select 
      GROUP_CONCAT(Case When Start = '2013-04-01' 
                        Then name ELSE NULL End) As '2013-04-01',
      GROUP_CONCAT(Case When Start = '2013-04-02' 
                        Then name End) As '2013-04-02',
      GROUP_CONCAT(Case When Start = '2013-04-03' 
                        Then name End) As '2013-04-03'
From Test;
```

then you will get output like this:

```
|   2013-04-01 |  2013-04-02 |    2013-04-03 |
----------------------------------------------
| Donald,Pluto | Daisy,Goofy | Mickey,Minnie |
```

This one is dynamic query for that:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Start = ''',
      `Start`,
      ''' THEN `name` ELSE NULL END) AS `',
      `Start`, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Test;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql,'
                     FROM Test
                  ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d01d7/3)

If there is a field something like `ID` you can do like this:

```
Select ID,
      GROUP_CONCAT(Case When Start = '2013-04-01' 
                        Then name ELSE NULL End) As '2013-04-01',
      GROUP_CONCAT(Case When Start = '2013-04-02' 
                        Then name End) As '2013-04-02',
      GROUP_CONCAT(Case When Start = '2013-04-03' 
                        Then name End) As '2013-04-03'
From Test2
GROUP BY ID;
```

Or dynamic query like this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Start = ''',
      `Start`,
      ''' THEN `name` ELSE NULL END) AS `',
      `Start`, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Test2;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ID, ', @sql,'
                     FROM Test2
                  GROUP BY ID
                  ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
| ID | 2013-04-01 | 2013-04-02 | 2013-04-03 |
---------------------------------------------
|  1 |     Donald |      Daisy |     Mickey |
|  2 |      Pluto |      Goofy |     Minnie |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f53f/3)

Comment: Thank you for this valuable contribution. This is the type of output that I was wanting.  It will take me some time to digest the code that you have provided.

Comment: I am examining your code now and my immediate reaction is to replace the value of ID with 'am' and 'pm'. Two questions; what change would i need to make to my data structure and subsequently to your code to so that 'am' and 'pm' appear where id 1 and 2 presently appear?  Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2593733 - Of then I got why is there two name for the same date? It is differentiated with 'am' and 'pm'. So you can group by that.

Comment: Great minds think alike.  It appears that we were posting the same suggestion simultaneously.

Comment: Any suggestions on implementing this in PHP.  This suggestion works for me in mySQL.  When I attempt to migrate it to php I get the following syntax error `Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select group_concat(distinct concat( 'group_concat(case when startd = `startd` ' at line 2.`

Comment: How can i pass the results of this dynamic query to a variable that I can loop over in PHP?

In the past I have used:

`$result=mysqli_query($con,"select ...");
... lines deleted ...
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
... lines deleted ...`

this method does not seem appropriate in these circumstances.